# Simple anagram finder using Scala and some Scalaz

Tags: scala, scalaz

I'd like to hear some thoughts on my simple anagram finder, written in Scala. I mainly wrote this as a first go at writing some serious Scala, and I wanted to try out the Scalaz library.

I'm coming from a Java background, with minimal experience with functional languages. Things I'd ideally like feedback on:

- Any improvements to make it less imperative
- Any other uses of library code, like Scalaz

I know that I've not covered all test cases, but this was enough to get me up and running.

#### General algorithm:

- Parse a list of words. Turn each word into lower case, sort alphabetically and treat that as the 'signature' of the word.
- Insert signature and word into a map, with the key being the signature, and the value being a set (or list) of words with the same signature
- Retrieval is simply looking up a word based on its signature

#### Signature class

```
case class Stem(word: String) {
  val stem: List[Char] = word.toLowerCase.trim.toList.sortWith((e1, e2) => (e1 < e2))

  override def equals(p1: Any) = p1 match {
    case s: Stem => s.stem == stem
    case _ => false
  }

  override def hashCode = stem.hashCode

  override def toString = stem.mkString("Stem(", "", ")")
}
```

**Notes**:

I'm sure I'd be able to take the word as a parameter and manipulate it to be in alphabetical order, rather than having a `stem` field. I'm sure I'd have been able to omit the `equals` and `hashCode` methods then, but I couldn't work out how to do that. I think maybe because I'm using a `case class` here?

#### Anagram Finder class

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

class AnagramFinder(words: List[String]) {
 
  implicit def string2Stem(s: String): Stem = Stem(s)
 
  val mapping = createMapping(words)
 
  def createMapping(words: List[String]) = {
    var anagrams: Map[Stem, Set[String]] = Map()
 
    words.foreach(s => anagrams = anagrams |+| Map(Stem(s) -> Set(s)))
 
    anagrams
  }
   
  def find(word: String): Option[Set[String]] = mapping.get(word)
}
```

**Notes**:

I really wanted to just have `anagrams |+| Map(Stem(s) -> Set(s))` in my `foreach`, but that required (a) using a mutable map instead, which I'd be fine with, but (b) having to write my own semigroup implementation for the mutable Map, which I struggled with.

Also, `anagrams |+| Map(Stem(s) -> Set(s))` isn't picking up my implicit String to Stem method. Why?

#### Anagrams object

```
object Anagrams {
 
  def apply(wordListFile: String, word: String) = {
    val finder = new AnagramFinder(scala.io.Source.fromFile(wordListFile).mkString.split('\n').toList)
    finder.find(word)
  }
}
```

**Notes**: I know I should initialise the word list into a `val` field on the object which can be reused between calls, but this was really just to get me started.

#### Appendix: Tests

```
class StemTest extends org.scalatest.FunSuite {
 
  test("Stem of noel is e,l,n,o") {
    assert(Stem("noel").stem == List('e','l','n','o'))
  }
 
  test("Stem of Hello is H,e,l,l,o") {
    assert(Stem("Hello").stem == List('H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'))
  }
 
  test("Stems of abc and cba are equal") {
    assert(Stem("abc") == Stem("cba"))
  }
}

class AnagramFinderTest extends FunSuite {
 
  test("List of words should create appropriate map") {
    val testMap:Map[Stem, Set[String]] = Map(Stem("abc") -> Set("cba"), Stem("def") -> Set("def"), Stem("ggz") -> Set("zgg"))
    val givenList = List("cba", "def", "zgg")
 
    val mapping = new AnagramFinder(givenList).mapping
    assert(mapping == testMap)
  }
   
  test("Same stemmed words should both exist in the map") {
    val testMap:Map[Stem, Set[String]] = Map(Stem("abc") -> Set("abc", "cba"))
    val givenList = List("abc", "cba")
 
    val mapping = new AnagramFinder(givenList).mapping
    assert(mapping == testMap)
  }
 
  test("Finding words") {
    val givenList = List("abc", "cba", "bob", "bca")
 
    val anagramFinder = new AnagramFinder(givenList)
 
    val foundAnagrams = anagramFinder.find("abc").get
 
    val expected = Set("abc", "bca", "cba")
 
    assert(foundAnagrams.forall(s => expected contains s))
    assert(expected.forall(s => foundAnagrams contains s))
  }
 
  test("Full test") {
 
    val expected = Some(Set("act", "cat", "Cat"))
    val actual = Anagrams("/usr/share/dict/words", "cat")
 
    assert(expected == actual)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some suggestions to improve your code:

`xs.sortWith((e1, e2) => (e1 < e2))` is identical to `xs.sorted`

If you are not interested in `Stem.word` you can place it into companions' apply-method:

```
object Stem {
  def apply(word: String): Stem = {
    val stem: List[Char] = word.toLowerCase.trim.toList.sorted
    new Stem(stem)
  }
}

case class Stem private(stem: List[Char])
```

---

`source.mkString.split('\n')` is identical to `source.getLines`

---

Whenever you want to sum-up something or use an accumulator, `fold` is what you are searching for:

```
(Map.empty[Stem, Set[String]] /: words) {
  case (map, word) => map + (Stem(word) -> Set(word))
}
```

With help of scalaz:

```
words.map(word => Map(Stem(word) -> Set(word))) reduceLeft { _|+|_ }
```

`reduce` is a `fold`: `xs.tail.fold(xs.head)(f)`

`/:` is a synonym for `foldLeft`: `(init /: xs)(f) == (xs foldLeft init)(f)`

---

Your implicit conversion `String => Stem` doesn't work in `string -> set` because `->` already needs an implicit conversion and you are not allowed to apply multiple ones at once. When you use tuple notation `(string, set)`, your implicit conversion is applied.